# SMD Component blown in earphone circuit in S9 mobile phone - please help identify and how?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, esd, tvs, mobile

[image: S9 Sub PBA Replacement board, not sure what components marked MT or 7 are]

[image: S9 Sub PBA earphone connector showing component blown]

Hi all,
I am trying to identify the components marked "MT" and "7" in the first picture.  They are in the earphone circuit of a UK Samsung S9 G960F mobile phone. The repair company said the component marked "MT" is an inductor and has blown due to accidental damage caused by a "voltage zap" and denied a warranty claim. One channel of the headphone output no longer works and the repair company said that swapping out the board does not fix the problem so there's a fault on the main board.

However, I believe the blown component might be a TVS diode but after much searching I have been unable to confirm either component.  Could an ESD strike or multiple strikes have caused it to fail open like this? What else could have caused this in normal use?

I am also struggling to understand the circuit here, unfortunately it's too small for me to be able to trace and the service manual does not include the circuit or component layout for this. If they are both TVS diodes, maybe they are unidirectional but then they would use two of the same component?  If one is a bidirectional TVS diode, what is the other component? If the component marked "MT" is an inductor it seems to be in place before the TVS diode and so maybe susceptible to an ESD strike?

The audio IC used is a CS47L93 and the data sheet for it recommends the use of TVS diodes as close as possible to the connector.  It also says it will work as an AUX output for connecting to other equipment, but I do not see any other protection circuitry apart from what I suspect are TVS diodes.  Should there be other protection circuitry to prevent DC / overvoltage / surge conditions?

I have maybe used the headphone socket about 20-30 times and have used it with one channel not working as I only really used headphones for directions and audio books while cycling.  I do have neoprene cycling overshoes and have walked over nylon carpets so I have experienced static shocks which is why I think it might be ESD related. I didn't know about ESD until this happened!

To give an idea of scale, the second picture shows the big metal USB-C connector on the right.  The components are too small for me to see without a magnifying glass or zoomed in photo as shown below. I measured the marked components which are 1mm in length indicating a 0402 package with 0201 capacitors around them.

I have found the component marked "7" in use in the headphone circuit in other mobile phones, the S7, S8, S9, Note8, Note9, the "MT" is also in the S8 with the same circuit.  They both seem to be in parallel with each other by looking at the traces and one side is ground.  On the G960U S9 board variant, the "7" components are missing and on the G9600 S9 variant the marked components are missing altogether and replaced by a single capacitor for each channel.

Someone has kindly measured the marked components out of circuit and found them to be open in either direction on the diode test and the maximum resistance range of his meter.

Thank you for your help and apologies if I have done something against the rules.

Comment: If ESD or overcurrent did that then it's likely that the DAC is burned to a crisp also. We can't really do component ID questions without dimensions and other identifiying information. With anything smaller than 0402, you have to pull the SMT off the board to identify most of them .  The picture at the top is also missing many components than the burned one.

Comment: Both the MT and 7 appear to have a stripe at one end. That would seem to indicate a polarized component, not an inductor. TVS is likely. Have you tried removing the burned blobs? There might not be usable pads left to resolder to. Very tricky repair.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
@VoltageSpike - I got some calipers and the components are 1mm in length indicating a 0402 package. The first photo is a close up of the components from a 0.6 rev board, the blown component is on a 0.7 rev board and is slightly different.
rdtsc - I didn't try repairing it as a replacement board is quite cheap and is what I used for the top photograph.  However, I want to understand the circuit and what it's capabilities are with a view to determining if the failure could be caused by normal use cases.
Any further help is appreciated!

Comment: I have now identified the components - they are both TVS diodes.  The "MT" TVS diode is a Diodes Incorporated D3V3H1B2LP and the "7" TVS diode is an RFSemi RDL1151B. They are both in parallel with each other on each headphone output.  I am guessing they have different ESD suppression characteristics - maybe one is more suited to fast transients, the other slower transients, but the "MT" diode is first in the firing line and so will take the brunt of any attacks.  I am not sure this is the best protection however - can anyone please comment and suggest a better approach?